# How does Android's messaging app handle the resending of failed messages

Tags: android, sms

In the weekend my phone chewed through $20 worth of credit by resending the same message over and over again after delivery initially failed. The phone company believes it is a software fault and they are not liable, but I'm not ready to just take their word for it.

I figured I'd dive into the Android source code to try and get a grasp on how message delivery actually works, but I'm not having much success. What I'm really trying to get to the bottom of is, how is the phone expected to know when delivery fails? And if the signal is very weak, could the phone theoretically send the message but not receive the acknowledgement and therefore assume the message had not been sent? Shouldn't the network recognize some sort of "cookie" being sent with the message and refuse to resend it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got anywhere with this. The phone company refunded the money.